# C# TSQL DDL with many values

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I have a label that's being populated via a two Dropdowns. However I want to clean up the selection and populating process as currently I think my frontend logic (ddl) is not executing in order. What I need is populate the number of records that exist (in the label). Also for those who want to query the backend first please note that this query works fine in MS SQL Server and I get back 1 record(s). Any suggestions? Thanks to all help.

C#:

```
        int sType = 0;
        if(ddlType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            //Clinical skills
            sType = 1;
        }
        else if (ddlType.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            //Response
            sType = 1;
        }
        else if (ddlType.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            //Behaviour
            sType = 1;
        }
        else if (ddlType.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            //bravery
            sType = 1;

        }
        else if (ddlType.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            //Clinical skills
            sType = 1;
        }
        else if (ddlType.SelectedIndex == 5)
        {
            //Clinical skills
            sType = 1;
        }

    if (ddlDivisionsCompliments.SelectedValue == "East Central")
    {
        string sSql = "SELECT RefNo AS [Records]" +
                       "FROM dbo.tbl_compliments " +
                       "WHERE (Compliment_Clinical = '" + sType + "' " +
                        " OR Compliment_Response = '" + sType + "' " +
                        " OR Compliment_Behaviour = '" + sType + "' " +
                        " OR Compliment_Bravery = '" + sType + "' " +
                        " OR Compliment_Teamwork = '" + sType + "' " +
                        " OR Compliment_Other = '" + sType + "' )" +
                        "AND Compliment_division = 'East Central '" +
                      "AND (ComplimentDate >= '" + sStart + "' " +
                      "AND ComplimentDate <= '" + sEnd + "' )";//+
        //"ORDER BY MIN(ComplimentDate)";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = DBConnect.DataReaderDataTable(sSql);


        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            divResults.Visible = false;
            divSave.Visible = true;
            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();
            lblCount.Text = "<strong><em>For this selection there are " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " record(s) in the database.</em></strong>";
        }
        else
        {
            divResults.Visible = false;
            gv.DataBind();
            lblCount.Text = "<strong>No records!</strong>";
            //lblCount.TextCssClass = "Alert";
        }


    }
```

SOLVED : Nested-ifs solved it. ;-) so the code I used might help someone else and this is below:

```
if (ddlDivisionsCompliments.SelectedItem.Value == "02")
        {

            if (ddlType.SelectedItem.Value == "01" )
            {


                string sSql = "SELECT RefNo AS [Records] " +
                               "FROM dbo.tbl_complaints " +
                               "WHERE (Compliment_Response = '" + sType + "' )" +
                                "AND Compliment_division = 'East Central' " +
                              "AND ComplimentDate >= '" + sStart + "' " +
                              "AND ComplimentDate <= '" + sEnd + "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : Nested-ifs solved it. ;-) so the code I used might help someone else and this is below:

```
if (ddlDivisionsCompliments.SelectedItem.Value == "02")
        {

            if (ddlType.SelectedItem.Value == "01" )
            {


                string sSql = "SELECT RefNo AS [Records] " +
                               "FROM dbo.tbl_complaints " +
                               "WHERE (Compliment_Response = '" + sType + "' )" +
                                "AND Compliment_division = 'East Central' " +
                              "AND ComplimentDate >= '" + sStart + "' " +
                              "AND ComplimentDate <= '" + sEnd + "' ";
```